# insert in a file (.txt) objects sorted depending an atribute in python

Tags: python, file, sorting

I want to insert objects in a file (.txt) sorted depending an atribute (score is the atribute in this case)

```
class list():

    def __init__(self, name, score):

        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def insert(self):

        outfile = open('list.txt', 'a') 
        outfile.write(self.name + ':' + self.score + '\n')
        outfile.close()
```

how can I do, to first check on the file to see all objects in the file and then insert an object in the best order.

(we want to make a ranking for a game, and every time that a users plays, we want to insert the user and the score sorted by the score)

Comment: read the file content in a list, append the new score to the list, write the list back to the file

Comment: do you need to show the file itself? If not, you can just put the name and score at the end and sort on the fly, when needed? otherwise you have to rewrite the file every time.

Comment: You should not name your class list, as this will override the built-in list.

Comment: 1. Will the *user* examine this file, or is it only to store the data for the benefit of the next time the program runs? 2. Do you need to store *all* scores or only some? Which ones if some?

Answer (score 0):

Just inserting in the write position is for a text file very hard. It is however easy to read the content, sort it and write it back again.
To properly sort it in you need to first read the data:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file_:
    string_list = file_.readlines()
```

The you read it into your `name : score` list format:

```
sorted_list = [line.split(':') for line in string_list]
```

You insert your element:

```
sorted_list.append([name, score])
```

and sort it for the second element:

```
sorted_list.sort(key = lambda (name, score): score)
```

Now you can write it back to a file

```
with open('list.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(['{0} : {1}'.format(name, score) for 
                        (name, score) in sorted_list])
```

This is a possibility to do what you want. Now you just have to rewrite it in class form.
So far you perform the sorting on strings, you can also convert the strings first to your type.

---

Possible class:

```
class my_list():

    def __init__(self, name, score):

        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.existing = None

    def read_list(self):
        with open('list.txt', 'r') as file_:
            string_list = file_.readlines()
        self.existing = [line.split(':') for line in string_list]

    def insert(self):
        if self.existing is None:
           self.existing = []
        self.existing.append([self.name, self.score])
        self.existing.sort(key = lambda (name, score): score)
        with open('list.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(['{0} : {1}\n'.format(name, score) for 
                                (name, score) in self.existing])
```

---

Probably better design of the class:

```
class my_list():
    def __init__(self, filename, score_type=int):
        self.filename = filename
        self.score_type = score_type
        self.existing = None
        self.read_list()

    def read_list(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as listfile:
            string_list = listfile.readlines()
        raw_list = [line.split(':') for line in string_list]
        self.existing = [[name.strip(), self.score_type(score.strip())] 
                         for name, score in raw_list]

    def insert(self, name, score):
        self.existing.append([name, score])

    def sort(self):
        self.existing.sort(key = lambda (name, score): score)

    def write_sorted(self):
        self.sort()
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(['{0} : {1}\n'.format(name, score) for
                                (name, score) in self.existing])

#testing it:
test = my_list('list.txt')
test.read_list()
test.insert('horst', 7)
test.write_sorted()
```

---

*Edit:*
-fixed naming issue
-modified second class to store `score` as `int`

Comment: we have tried this code, introducing: 
m=my_list("Ander",5)
m.read_list()
m.insert()

and we have this: NameError: global name 'sorted_list' is not defined

Comment: I added a second code example class, which I think is likely the better design. Note however, that name and score are still treated as string and sorted accordingly. You could provide additional types and cast the read values.

Comment: it works properly if I am doing from 0 to 9.
but I have tried with bigger numbers and there are mistakes:
for example: 
inigo : 0

inigo : 0

jon : 1

jon : 100

horst : 7

jon : 70

jon : 9

Comment: That is the behavior I explained, score is a string so far, and hence sorted as a string. If you want an integer instead you have the change the code accordingly. If this is the only case then just give scores as an integer `test.insert('name', 10)` and change the reading part by replacing `score.strip()` by `int(score.strip())`. Likely you can drop the `strip()` part.

Comment: @jmarco10 I tried to implement what I think you want in the second version of the `my_list` class now. Pleas test if it is what you need, if so accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to keep your score data in memory instead writing to file over and over. Just write to file when it's strictly necessary, think that reading/writing from/to memory is faster than disk access. Here's a little basic example of what I mean with a simple basic usage:

```
import json
import pprint
import random


class Score():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def load(self, filename='score.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)

    def save(self, filename='score.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.data, f)

    def insert(self, name, score):
        self.data.append((name, score))
        self.data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return pprint.pformat(self.data, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Score()

    names = ["Peter", "Jhon", "Lewis", "Sam"]
    for i in range(10):
        s.insert(random.choice(names), random.randint(0, 1000))

    print(s)
    s.save("score1.txt")
    print('-' * 80)

    for i in range(10):
        s.insert(random.choice(names), random.randint(0, 1000))

    print(s)
    s.save("score2.txt")
    print('-' * 80)

    s.load("score1.txt")
    print(s)
```

Have in mind the above example can be improved quite a lot, if your final score data structure is not going to be huge this approach will be fine though. Otherwise, you can think of using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module so you can keep an already sorted structure so you don't need to sort over and over. And if things start getting more complex than a simple game, probably you'll need to start considering another more efficient data structures, like databases. Anyway, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: As the initial question didn't have the list in memory it probably is not need. Hence I would move the `sort` part to `save`. Then you only sort once you really write it, not every time you insert an element. But I think this depends on the implementation of sort.

Comment: our main problem is that if we use 'w' it overwrittes the file and if we use 'a', appears an error saying: ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 15 - line 1 column 17 (char 14 - 16).